# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have just downloaded latest chromedriver from `http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads` and the version is `ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30`.

But when I am trying to run

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

its showing me the following error message.

```
/Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/python/scrapping/venv/bin/python /Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/python/scrapping/index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/python/scrapping/index.py", line 6, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/python/scrapping/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/python/scrapping/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/python/scrapping/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/python/scrapping/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/shahanurmdsharif/development/python/scrapping/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84


Process finished with exit code 1
```

While i am using right version `84.0.4147.30`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of Chrome installed on your machine ?

Comment: latest version ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30

Comment: I am asking about Chrome browser and not chromedriver. Chrome browser 84 stable version is not release yet https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule.

Comment: ok, Google Chrome is up to date
Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Then you need to use ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two things:

1. Both browser and WebDriver should compulsorily be of same version.
2. browser=webdriver.Chrome('path_to_your_webriver')

Comment: Thank you, it works successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you need to use exact chrome driver version according to chrome browser version
please check your browser version and download driver exe from   https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and use it .

Comment: Thank you, it works successfully